# Like/Unlike button functionality

Tags: android, android-activity, android-sqlite

It may seem foolish but need a suggestion that how to implement like/unlike button functionality means when shall we call the api because user may continue to click the button multiple times.

I thought to maintain a flag but at what time i will call the api then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just disable the button once user clicked, then call api, enable it again in after getting response in onPostExecute() method.

Comment: In case if the user is continuously tapping on button then there will be lots of runninh requests.

Comment: For that only i'm telling you to disable the button, after disabling the button if user clicks again , nothing will happen. After enabling the button only they can click again. You have to call the api in OnClickListener.

Comment: But facebook does not do like this. If i am on 2g network, it will take time to get the response, so as per your suggestion the button is disabled. But facebook on 2g network, like unlike buttom works quickly

Comment: Facebook will be having separate server for those kind of services needs rapid response, their server configurations also very high. Or else you can use Handler, set a boolean flag, when user clicks button check the flag, if it is true then start handler and set the flag false, wait for 2 to 5 seconds and perform api call, then set the flag true again in onPostExecute.

Answer (score 0):

Use toggle buttons [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html)

```
ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togglebutton);
toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            // The toggle is enabled means "like" in your case // call api for like
        } else {
            // The toggle is disabled means "dislike" in your case // call api for dislike
        }
    }
});
```